# MySQL Subtracting 1 month from birthdate and changing date to current if NULL

Tags: mysql

Here is my code:

```
SELECT FirstName, DATE_SUB(BirthDate, interval 1 month)
from Student
where IFNULL(Birthdate, now());
```

The idea for this statement is to return the student's birthday minus 1 MONTH, else if the student's BIRTHDAY=NULL change that to current date.

I am just struggling to return the current date when given a NULL birthday. My table still outputs NULL in these situations.

Comment: Do you want to subtract 1 month from the current date if the birthdate is null?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this way:

```
SELECT
    FirstName,
    IF(BirthDate IS NULL, NOW(), DATE_SUB(BirthDate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
FROM
    Student;
```

Or this way, if you want to subtract 1 month from NOW() too.

```
SELECT
    FirstName,
    DATE_SUB(IFNULL(BirthDate, NOW()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
FROM
    Student;
```

Comment: Or `DATE_SUB(IFNULL(BirthDate, NOW()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked perfectly I was stuck trying to use a WHERE clause when I didn't need to.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for your feedback, it was added to the answer. I'm glad it worked Poggers99, if you have time, mark the answer as correct, it will be appreciated, thanks.